# Recommend a book about compact subgroups

Tags: topological-groups, reference-request, textbook-recommendation

Hi, could you please recommend me some books/articles where I could find information about compact subgroups of metric topological compact (abelian) groups? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- "*The structure of compact groups*", written by "*Karl Heinrich Hofmann*" and "*Sydney A. Morris*", 2nd edition, 2006 (for a newer version, 2020, see https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110695991).

2-"*Representations of Finite and Compact Groups*", written by "*Barry Simon*", 1995, published by American Mathematical Society (AMS).

3-"*Introduction to the Representation Theory of Compact and Locally Compact Groups*", written by "*Alain Robert*", 1983, published by Cambridge University Press (see https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511661891).

The first time I heard about topological groups was at a harmonic analysis course during my master, the lecturer was Mohammad Tabatabei (https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Smohammad-Tabatabaie-2/research).

Comment: I am not sure why some combination of Hewitt-Ross and Hofmann-Morris would not suffice, rather than contacting some professor working on some kind of harmonic analysis